# Which Seam component to use: <h:outputLink> or <h:commandLink>?

Tags: seam

I'm very new to Seam and am just getting used to the different components available. I'm wondering which one I should use for this situation.

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink) question explains the difference between `<h:outputLink>` and `<h:commandLink>`, that `<h:outputLink>` produces just a basic HTML link tag with GET request and `<h:commandLink>` submits a POST via a click event.

I just want to attach a simple jQuery click event to a link. I don't want the link to redirect to anywhere or submit a form. I basically want the equivalent of href="#" (I understand that commandLink generates href="#" but it seems heavy-handed for a simple link with no form submission). But `<h:outputLink>` implicitly adds an href value unless I put value="#" (which seems hacky).

What component do I want to use here? I seem to be missing some very basic element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(First: `<h:outputLink>` and `<h:commandLink>` are standard JSF components, not part of the Seam framework.) In this case, you can just use the standard HTML tag `<a>`, because you appear not to be using anything special to JSF.